# Similar matrices question

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm doing an online assignment for my linear algebra course and I've come to a question that is asking me to tick true or false on each question. I get three attempts and I've used two of them up and I have no idea why I am wrong. The question is:

Given A,B ∈ Mnxn(F).
 Which of the following statements are true:

(a)A and B are similar if and only if there exists an invertible matrix P ∈ Mnxn(F) such that TP∘TA=TB∘Tp

(b)If A and B are similar, then TA(X) = TB(X) for all x ∈F^n

(c)If TA(x) = TB(x) for all x ∈Fn, then A and B are similar.

(d)If A and B are similar, then rank(Ta) = rank(Tb).

(e)If A and B are similar, then nullity (Ta) = nullity (Tb).

(f)If A and B are similar, then rank(A) = rank(B).

(g) If A and B are similar, then nullity(A) = nullity(B).

We haven't gone over anything from rank/nullity yet so I initially presumed that all of those to do with rank/nullity will be false. We do occasionally get set questions beyond our ability by mistake but I would appreciate someones input. I Though (a) was true although I'm not certain. I thought the rest where false though. Where have I gone wrong?

EDIT: I have looked over it now and think that (b) and (c) are the only false one's, anyone think I'm still wrong?

Comment: *so I initially presumed that all of those to do with rank/nullity will be false* Hm, not a very effective learning strategy. Did you try to look them up since then?

Comment: Haha, yeah I have. I found out that (f) and (g) are indeed true but I'm not sure about (d) and (e). I'm think as the matrix's have the same nullity and rank the transition must as well. What I'm most interested in though if someone could confirm that (a) is true and (b) and (c) are false.

Comment: If I may ask, what is "T"?

Comment: I can't help more because the statements are not clear. Please edit carefully, letting us know for example what $T$ is.

Comment: T is the matrix transformation where TA(x) = A*x and TB(x)=B*x.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ and $B$ are similar, ie $A=PBP^{-1}$, then we can see them both as metrix representations of some linear transformation, with respect to (possibly) different bases (one basis gives rise to $A$ the other to $B$). The key point here is that the range and kernel of the linear transformation can be worked out from its matrix representation, and they are clearly invariant under the choice of basis. So then the rank and nullity must be the same.

You can use this fact to look at the remaining statements (they are not exactly clear the way they are written at the moment).

Comment: Thanks that's a really good explanation! You wouldn't be able to tell me more about any of (a) (b) or (c) would you? I'm thinking that A is true with b and c false, although not certain. I'm particular not sure about (c) as if If TA(x) = TB(x) then A=B and I'm not sure if that means they are similar.

Comment: @user108412 What happens if you put $P = I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix, in the similarity formula from Any's answer?